# How to create a React Native component library?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

How do I create a React Native component library?

I want to import it using:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either publish it on NPM, or just use a github dependency. This applies to any library, and is not react specific.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies